# Moving mouse with webdriver in Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Iam using Moving mouse with webdriver in Firefox..but i think function is working because Menu link color is changing..but sub menu is not diplaying..manually if I touch the menu submenu is dispalying

my action code is here

```
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("EManagement"));
Assert.assertEquals(true, menu.isDisplayed());              
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).click().perform();               
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("Management")).click();
```

but i am getting error like Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

My Firefox version is 18.0.2 and Selenium version is 2.33
Anybody can help me

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem and you can use the following java script.

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
         + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
         ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.driver).executeScript(javaScript, element);
```